# android Regex issue

Tags: android, regex

I had an issue with this regex:

```
(\{(([^\p{Space}][^\p{Punct}])+)\})
```

The problem is in number of chars. If I typing even number of chars it's works, when odd - not. I was trying to replace '+' with '?' or '*', but result still the same. How can I fix this?

I expect from this regex to block such strings: {%,$ #fd}. And allow this:
{F} or {F242fFSf23}.

Comment: What are the pattern requirements? What are you trying to match? Currently, it matches  a `{`, then 1 or more repetitions of 2 chars, a non-space and then a non-punctuation, and then a `}`, hence you cannot use 1 char in between `{...}`

Comment: When you are trying to replace + then how even or odd numbers are coming into the picture?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm trying to block user from entering such string: {%F ,2}. And allow only to type: {Ffrgr2443fdfd}

Comment: Try `\{[^\p{Punct}\p{Space}]+\}` or `\{[^\p{P}\p{S}\s]+\}` or even `\{\p{Alnum}+\}` or `\{[A-Za-z0-9]+\}`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You're awesome. First and second regex working. Thank you!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Can you help me with groups in regex? I can create new question

Comment: Which groups? What do you mean? You may keep your groups in my patterns, `\{([A-Za-z0-9]+)\}`. Note you don't need a group around the whole pattern as there are no use cases in Java/Android/Kotlin to justify that kind of capturing group use.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have such regex: ([+*/\-]|(([^\p{Alpha}]|(\{[A-Za-z0-9]+\}))+)|([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+|(\{[A-Za-z0-9]+\}))+ And I want to replace repetition with groups. Can I do this?

Comment: [Your pattern](https://regex101.com/r/GHuLab/1) looks corrupt to me. Please edit the fiddle to include strings you have with expected results.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183285/discussion-between-skullper-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, it matches a `{`, then 1 or more repetitions of 2 chars, a non-space and then a non-punctuation, and then a `}`, hence you cannot use 1 char in between `{...}`.

To fix that, you need to use both the character classes inside bracket expression:

```
\{[^\p{Punct}\p{Space}]+\}
```

or

```
\{[^\p{P}\p{S}\s]+\}
```

**Details**

- `\{` - a `{` char
- `[^\p{Punct}\p{Space}]+` - 1 or more repetitons (`+`) of any char that does not belong to the `\p{Punct}` (punctuation) or `\p{Space}` (whitespace) class.
- `\}` - a `}`.

Note that if the contents between the braces can only include ASCII letters or digits (in regex, `[A-Za-z0-9]+`), you may even use a mere

```
\{[A-Za-z0-9]+\}
```

Answer (score 0):

Disassembling your regex... the reason why it only accepts an even number in between is the following part:

```
([^\p{Space}][^\p{Punct}])+
```

This basically means: something which isn't a space, exactly 1 character and something which isn't a ~punct, exactly 1 character and this several times... so exactly 1 + exactly another 1 are exactly 2 characters... and this several times will always be even.

So what you probably rather want is the following:

```
[^\p{Space}\p{Punct}]+
```

for the part shown above... which will result in the following for your complete regex:

```
\{[^\p{Space}\p{Punct}]+}
```

that of course can be simplified even more. I leave that up to you.